# Grails oauth plugin external configuration in production mode

Tags: grails, oauth

I'm using grails oauth plugin standard configuration as part of Config.groovy

```
environments {
    production {
        oauth {
            providers {
                linkedin {
                    api = LinkedInApi
                    key = 'mykey'
                    secret = 'mySecret'
                    successUri = "/userLogin/linkedinLogin"
                    callback = "https://myserverdomain/oauth/linkedin/callback"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When using the same configuration in external file and reference it by

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:external-config.groovy"]
```

There is an error "*No oauth configuration found. Please configure the oauth scribe plugin*".

Notice: 
1. other configuration properties are working fine. 
2. Problem exist only in production mode. Using the same configuration file in development mode works fine.

Comment: where is the external config file placed?

Comment: The external config file is read successfully. Since I print its content. It is actually in tomcat temp directory [file:/var/cache/tomcat7/temp/local_config.groovy] file permissions is 644

Comment: Can you add the exact configuration? I see environments is not closed (missing `}`) may be a copy paste error. I suppose that is not the way you have in the config file.

Comment: copy&paste issue - I've added the extra }. Obviously this is not the issue.

Comment: Also noticed that grails.serverURL is not getting populated from the external file. Only the value in Config.groovy holds.